# What is the difference between media and site_media folders?

Tags: django, pinax

What is the difference between the two folders? I created an example project in Pinax and sometimes they put stuff in media and other times site_media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe MEDIA Is used for uploaded files while site_media is for static files.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/

Although the following quote is about staticfiles I think it covers the difference:

> In previous versions of Django, it was common to place static assets
>   in MEDIA_ROOT along with user-uploaded files, and serve them both at
>   MEDIA_URL. Part of the purpose of introducing the staticfiles app is
>   to make it easier to keep static files separate from user-uploaded
>   files.
>
> For this reason, you need to make your MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL
>   different from your STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL. You will need to
>   arrange for serving of files in MEDIA_ROOT yourself; staticfiles does
>   not deal with user-uploaded files at all. You can, however, use
>   django.views.static.serve() view for serving MEDIA_ROOT in
>   development; see Serving other directories.

Comment: Ok I think it might actually be the other way around though but thanks for the answer.